# Append the result from operation on list elements in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am stuck on this problem for a while now.

Suppose I have some facts like so:

```
function([1,2,3],['A']).
function([4,5,6],['B']).
```

And I want to write a predicate like so:

```
mapSomeList(List,Result)
```

which can transform, say, the list of `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]` into `['A','B','A']`.

How can I use recursion to implement `mapSomeList`?

What I have tried:

```
mapSomeList([],[]).
mapSomeList([X|Rest],Result):-
    function(X,Letter),
    append(Letter,[X],Result),
    mapSomeList(X,Rest).
```

But it just would not return the `Result`.

Thanks!

Comment: List in mapSomeList() does not necessarily have only three elements. Just wondering how are supposed to approach this in general?

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to solve this: one with `append/3` and one without.

Solution 1 with `append/3`:

```
mapSomeList([],L,L).
mapSomeList([H|T],LT,LO):-
    function(H,F),
    append(LT,F,LT1),
    mapSomeList(T,LT1,LO).

mapSomeList(List,Result):-
    mapSomeList(List,[],Result).

?- mapSomeList([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]],L).
L = [['A'], ['B'], ['A']]
```

Solution 2 without `append/3`:

```
mapSomeList([],[]).
find_pair([H|T],[F|T1]):-
    function(H,F),
    mapSomeList(T,T1).

?- mapSomeList([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]],L). 
L = [['A'], ['B'], ['A']]
```

Differences? Try to run the two goals inside `time/1` (i used SWISH)

`?- time(find_pair([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]],L)).`

with `append/3`: `14 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (92% CPU, 378757 Lips)`

without `append/3`: `6 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (79% CPU, 377169 Lips)`

So, you can see, already from this simple example, that the solution without append is faster.